# Pinning cloth physics to multiple objects in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, cloth-simulation

thanks to the help of some good people from this group, I was able to create procedural window blinds with moving slats.
Now I want to add some ropes that are connected to each slat and apply Cloth physics to that rope so that it behaves like in the real world. It means it bends when slats are moving up and stacking on each other.
I have no idea how to start with it and if it is even possible in Blender.
My slats are the instances created on points that come from a line. Now I want the rope to be generated based on the window blinds size and connected properly (each section to the corresponding slat). Then I want physics to be assigned so that this rope moves and bends when slats are moved and rotated (moving and rotation are realized through translate and rotate instances nodes in Geometry Nodes).
Is it doable?

[image]

Comment: pls add images, sketches of what you have and what you wanna have. And a blend file will always attract more people to your question...